# Creating message using Microsoft Graph produces UnableToDeserializePostBody

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I know this question has been asked before, but wanted to re-open in case there is some solution now. I am using Graph to try and create an email in a specific folder, using this POST:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/jjmckay912@outlook.com/mailFolders/AQMkADA...4qUAAAA=/messages
```

I am sending a base64 encoded MIME payload, with the content type of "text/plain". I get http error 400 with the error message ""code":"UnableToDeserializePostBody","message":"were unable to deserialize"

I am certain that my encoded MIME is correct, because if I use this url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/jjmckay912@outlook.com/messages
```

then the POST works fine. Except that the message ends up in the DRAFTS folder, whereas I want to put it in a specific folder. I am also as certain as I can be that the Id value I'm using is correct for the folder I'm writing to. Can anybody suggest a solution?  Or a way to bring this to the attention of Microsoft, in hopes of getting them to fix it?

Bye the way, the Microsoft documentation that says my code should work is here:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http
```

One more thing, I have tried using the "move" API to get the newly created message into my target, but the message remains in "draft" mode. Any way to remove that status?

Comment: It's a well know issue https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+Mime . Doc's and the SDK have issues https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs-contrib/issues/776 but its seem hard to get any traction to get it fixed